# Swift Core Audio Learning Resources

Tags: ios, swift, core-audio

I am trying to learn iOS Core Audio for Swift. I started out with Swift right away and I got no understanding of Objective-C. I am an Engineer with training in Sound engineering so I don't need to learn the basics of "sound" (samplerate, bitdepth, etc.) just the way it is approached in Core Audio, iOS, Swift.

Can you recommend any tutorials, guides, documentations or books (free or paid doesn't matter) that explain how to use Core Audio in Swift?

Thanks for your support,
Tobias

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Chris Adamson's [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321636848) is in Objective-C, but covers Core Audio quite well. Ask The Google for his name and you'll find some of his articles.
Many things transfer to Swift fairly easily. My [blog](http://rockhoppertech.com/blog) has several examples.

Core MIDI is another thing though. Swift support of Core MIDI is still problematic.

Comment: Hello Gene De Lisa thanks for the reply! I read through your blog and it seems that the new AVAudioEngine is what I need for now. Thanks you for the useful resources. I will have a try on the book you recommended to see if I can get my head around the Objectove-C syntax after playing around with the AVAudioEngine. Best, Tobias!

Comment: Glad to be of help. Don't hesitate to ask if there's something confusing.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned the Learning Core Audio book is a great resource. And currently it's not a problem that it's in Objective-C only, because now there are all the book's examples rewritten with Swift: https://github.com/AlesTsurko/LearningCoreAudioWithSwift2.0

Comment: This repository is currently being translated to swift 3.0 by me and hopefully will be re-translated again in swift 4.0.

Comment: @DimaGimburg can you please provide us a github repo link to the translated version?

Comment: swift 5 https://github.com/derekli66/Learning-Core-Audio-Swift-SampleCode

Answer (score 4):

Look for the [2014 WWDC Videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/). You want to watch:

- [What's New in Core Audio](http://asciiwwdc.com/2014/sessions/501)
- [AVAudioEngine in Practice](http://asciiwwdc.com/2014/sessions/502)

Comment: Hello ruoho ruotsi Thanks for the resources. The AVAudioEngine seems to be sufficient to play around with audio until I find some more resources on Core Audio.

Answer (score 0):

@TobiasSchmidt This might be a little outdated, but nevertheless you are on the right track to use swift for core-audio. Here is another example of someone else using @GeneDeLisa's biolderplate swift AVAudioEngine to create a synth[1]. A mental note for myself to get STK in to the mix using this[2]  and start making noise with Swift. For now, contented learning Objective-C as that is still the mainstay and has lot more mileage on CoreAudio. 
[1]http://flexmonkey.blogspot.com/2014/10/sound-synthesis-in-swift-core-audio.html
[2]http://arielelkin.github.io/articles/mandolin/

Comment: could not edit because the edit is less than 6 characters but please remove the following "/" after second link, otherwise you get 404